# Problems with try and catch in js

Tags: javascript

I can't understand why does it always output a mistake and catch block is never executed.

```
const box = {
   locked: true,
   unlock() { this.locked = false; },
   lock() { this.locked = true;  },
   _content: [],
   get content() {
     if (this.locked) throw new Error("Locked!");
     return this._content;
   }
 };
 function withBoxUnlocked(funct){
     try{
         console.log(funct);// thinks that everything is fine although there is a mistake
         box.lock();
     }
     catch(e){//why doesn't it execute catch block ?
         console.log("used catch");
         box.unlock();
         withBoxUnlocked(funct);
     }
 }
 withBoxUnlocked(box.content);
```

Answer (score 0):

At this point in your code:

```
withBoxUnlocked(box.content);
```

the runtime will have to invoke the getter function. That happens **before** the function is called.  Thus the `try/catch` inside the function is never reached.

You could change things to demonstrate what's going on by changing the way the `withBoxUnlocked()` function works:

```
function withBoxUnlocked(object, property){
     try{
         console.log(object[property]);// thinks that everything is fine although there is a mistake
         box.lock();
     }
     catch(e){//why doesn't it execute catch block ?
         console.log("used catch");
         box.unlock();
         withBoxUnlocked(object, property);
     }
 }
 withBoxUnlocked(box, "content");
```

That way, no attempt is made to access the property until the `try` clause is reached.